# grails URL not containing app.name on one system, but showing up fine on another

Tags: grails

We have two QA sites: they should be identical,  but their generated links behave differently.

On one case, the generated links contain the app.name.  In the other case, the links do not contain the app.name and are failing with a 404 error.

good link:  devici1/appName/controller/action 
bad  link:  devici2/controller/action  <-- notice the missing appName

Now here is what is weird:

- Both systems are running the same version of code, the links are
  generated using g.createLink(controller: entry.controller, action:
  entry.action)
- We do not set app.context anywhere that I know of. 
  It is not in application.properties, config.groovy, or the
  icw-config.groovy (local override file).
- Both systems  set app.name in application.properties
- grails.serverUrl is not set (we stopped using it more than a year ago)

Further,  this may have been going on for several months and no one noticed it on the bad system, so there is no recent change I can go looking for.

Does anyone know the logic used by g:createLink to determine when the app.name should be included or not?  Any suggestions for variables I should make sure are set or not set would be most appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked if your tomcat installation is the same?  I'm not 100% sure if createlink uses it but you can remove the context path in tomcat which might explain your app.name disappearing.  Also, you might check the versions of the JVMs you are running on each machine.

Comment: Seems you have two systems. So you have two copies of the grails deployment? You have two copies of tomcat installation on these separate systems? Check %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/Catalina/localhost/ check for XML configuring a context path for the app, wipe out %CATALINA_HOME%/work/ folder in case something is being cached, compare %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/ between the two tomcat instances that are not behaving the same way. Is there a custom library installed under %CATALINA_HOME%/lib on one but not the other tomcat installation? A good file compare tool will help you. I like Beyond Compare.